# Pandas: Pivot to columnar, ignore index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a pandas convention/function for pivoting data into columns ignoring the row indexes and just generating new indexes. This is the best I can do and it's so ugly.

```
# Example data from https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-pandas-pivot-tables-e0641d0c6c70
df = pd.read_excel(
   "https://github.com/datagy/pivot_table_pandas/raw/master/sample_pivot.xlsx",
   parse_dates=["Date"],
   engine="openpyxl",
)

>>>df.head()
```

|  | Date | Region | Type | Units | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-07-11 00:00:00 | East | Children's Clothing | 18 | 306 |
| 1 | 2020-09-23 00:00:00 | North | Children's Clothing | 14 | 448 |
| 2 | 2020-04-02 00:00:00 | South | Women's Clothing | 17 | 425 |
| 3 | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | East | Children's Clothing | 26 | 832 |
| 4 | 2020-03-19 00:00:00 | West | Women's Clothing | 3 | 33 |

```
#using the field 'Units' as an example
columns = []
for value in df["Type"].unique():
    single_column = df[df["Type"] == value]["Units"].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
    single_column.name = x
    columns.append(a)

# concat along column
pd.concat(columns,axis=1)
```

|  | Children's Clothing | Women's Clothing | Men's Clothing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18 | 17 | 10 |
| 1 | 14 | 3 | 30 |
| 2 | 26 | 33 | 27 |
| 3 | 18 | 12 | 5 |
| 4 | 34 | 29 | 21 |
| 419 | nan | 25 | nan |
| 420 | nan | 12 | nan |
| 421 | nan | 19 | nan |
| 422 | nan | 17 | nan |
| 423 | nan | 25 | nan |

**Edit** - *middle rows removed for brevity*

Comment: you can just reset (and rename) the index at last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

Try:

```
out=(df.reset_index()
    .pivot(index='index',columns='Type',values='Units')
    .apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull)
    .dropna(how='all')
    .rename_axis(columns=None,index=None))
```

**OR**

```
out=df[['Type','Units']]
out=(out.reset_index()
    .set_index(['index','Type'])
    .unstack(1)
    .apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull)
    .droplevel(0,1)
    .dropna(how='all')
    .rename_axis(columns=None,index=None))
```

output of `out`:

```
        Children's Clothing     Men's Clothing  Women's Clothing
    0       18.0                10.0            17.0
    1       14.0                30.0            3.0
    2       26.0                27.0            33.0
    3       18.0                5.0             12.0
    4       34.0                21.0            29.0
    ...     ...                 ...             ...
   419      NaN                 NaN             25.0
   420      NaN                 NaN             12.0 
   421      NaN                 NaN             19.0
   422      NaN                 NaN             17.0
   423      NaN                 NaN             25.0

424 rows × 3 columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.pivot`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','A','B','B'], 'col2':[10,20,15,25,30]})
df_pivot = pd.pivot(df, columns=['col1'], values=['col2'])
df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
print(df_pivot)

col1    A     B
0     10.0   NaN
1     20.0   NaN
2     15.0   NaN
3     NaN    25.0
4     NaN    30.0
```